# Drupal: how to disable edit tabs on the front-end?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

when I login as user to my drupal website I can see the tabs in the front-end to edit the content.

I would like to disable these tabs (end edit the content from the back-end only). How can I do it?

If I'm not wrong, I remember there was a back-end setting for it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're backend is a different theme than the front end (recommended), you can comment out $tabs and $tabs2 in the website theme.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the "Tab Tamer" [module](http://drupalmodules.com/module/tab-tamer). It will allow you to mange almost all tabs in Drupal from a single admin page.

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is not see the 'View|Edit' tabs, then another simple way to do this is to modify the theme CSS file.  It sounds like the following addition to the CSS should work:

```
.content-header .tabs
{
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to be more specific about which node type to do this to then name the CSS section as '.node-type-? .content-header .tabs' where the '?' is replaced with the name of the node type.